# Why my response data is not being shown in the postman and how do I see the request data in Django

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .serializers import TodoSerializer
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .models import Todo
from .models import User

class TodoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer
    queryset = Todo.objects.all()

    def get_object(request):
        return "Added";

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()


    def get_object(request):
        print("request", request)
        return "Registered";

class LoginView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    #serializer_class = UserSerializer
    #queryset = User.objects.all()
    #print("queryset = ",queryset[len(queryset)-1].email_id)
    #print("serializer_class = ",serializer_class)

    def get_object(self,request):
        return HttpResponse("request")


# Create your views here.
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
from todo import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'users', views.UserView)
router.register(r'todos', views.TodoView)
router.register(r'login', views.LoginView)

print("In url file")

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),    
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This is my views.py file and urls.py file.
I have a model created for user, with fields- email_id and password
CRUD operations are implemented automatically, so how do I validate data passed from the login form in frontend
Please tell me what's wrong in the code. I am not able to do the login part.

Comment: what is the default authentication class you are using?

Comment: I am not using any authentication class here, I don't know how it works.

Comment: For login functionality, u don't need to implement it urself. U can use web token for authentication system, `djangorestframework-simplejwt` is my recommendation. All you to do is make post request to the `token` url, it will give you access token key and use that token to get the validate data. Read more about it

Comment: Okay, I will try it.